# Convert a PDF to TIFF using Linux command line (FAX)

Tags: linux, pdf, tiff, fax

I would like to convert PDF to TIFF for fax usage. I need to keep quality as much as possible but I want to have a small duration (as little grey as possible).
I know Copia which does a wonderful job but I would like to have a Linux command line tool.

Do you know solutions (even non-free or non-opensource) which exists?

The basic image conversion tools everyone knows can do fax tiff but quality is poor and duration is high...

Thank you!

Comment: superuser.stackexchange or similar

Answer (score 1):

It slow down the process quite a bit but you can use supersamping to get better quality:

`convert -density 288 input.pdf -resize 25% output.tif`

From [imagemagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7223).